# Oracle SQLPlus: Echo without line numbers?

Tags: sql, oracle, logging, plsql, sqlplus

I'm working on a solution where several SQL and PL/SQL scripts are being run together, in a batch of sorts, via SQL*Plus.

I'm declaring `SET ECHO OFF;` and `SET ECHO ON;` at relevant points in the scripts so as to output relevant code.

Currently the output looks something like this:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      ct number := 0;
  3      ctChanges number := 0;
  4  
  5  BEGIN
  6      select count(*) into ct from ...
  7  (...rest of code block...)
"some specific status message"
Commit executed.
```

We keep this output as a run-log in our build-environment, but can also access it as a plain text file.

One downside of this format however, is that if I'd like to copy a certain section of the code and run it again in an IDE (like Toad or SQL Developer), it's hard to exclude the line numbers.

**Is it possible to tell SQL*Plus to output the code as above, but without including the line numbers?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use options [`sqlnumber` and `sqlprompt`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm):

```
set sqlprompt ''
set sqlnumber off
```

> `SET SQLN[UMBER] {ON|OFF}`
>
> SET `SQLNUMBER` is not supported in iSQL*Plus
>
> Sets the prompt for the second and subsequent lines of a SQL command or PL/SQL block. `ON` sets the prompt to be the line number. `OFF` sets the prompt to the value of `SQLPROMPT`.

Comment: Brilliant. So simple, once you know what to look for! Thanks!